# Create Table With Inserts For MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am learning mysql and am attempting to insert data into tables.  However, I am getting the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO PrevYear
>   VALUES ('ea12', '100', '2018-01-10', 'Sam Smith')' at line 11

And this is DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `PrevYear` (
  `EmployeeNumber` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `SaleAmount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SaleDate` date NOT NULL,
  `EmployeeName` char(17) NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE `CurrentYear` (
  `EmployeeNumber` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `SaleAmount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SaleDate` date NOT NULL,
  `EmployeeName` char(17) NOT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO CurrentYear
VALUES ('ea12', '100', '2019-01-10', 'Sam Smith');

INSERT INTO CurrentYear
VALUES ('ea12', '199', '2019-01-13', 'Sam Smith');

INSERT INTO CurrentYear
VALUES ('ea12', '100', '2019-03-01', 'Sam Smith');

INSERT INTO CurrentYear
VALUES ('ls22', '100', '2019-05-01', 'Sam Smith');


INSERT INTO PrevYear
VALUES ('ea12', '100', '2018-01-10', 'Sam Smith');

INSERT INTO PrevYear
VALUES ('ea12', '199', '2018-01-13', 'Sam Smith');

INSERT INTO PrevYear
VALUES ('ea12', '100', '2018-03-01', 'Sam Smith');

INSERT INTO PrevYear
VALUES ('ls22', '100', '2018-05-01', 'Sam Smith');
```

Comment: just add `;` after `create table` query's and it works fine https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cymWFQiZ6phZLafvTJcejm/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the most likely cause of the problem is that the CREATE TABLE statements also need to be terminated with `;`.